# exclude a folder and match all .html pattern files in a root folder using regex

Tags: regex, drupal, migration

I am doing migration from html to Drupal. Using migrate module.

Here in our custom migration script i need to match all .html files from all the folder except images folder.

pass this regex to `$list_files = new MigrateListFiles([],[],$regex)`

Below is format of html files

```
/magazines/sample.html 
/test/index.html
/test/format_ss1.html
/test/folder/newstyle_1.html
/images/two.html
```

i need to get only first 2 html files i.e., we are exluding files which ends with '_[0-9]' and '_ss[0-9]' and .hmtl files in images folder.

i have successfully done by excluding 3 and 4 but i can't able to excule .html files in images folder.

```
$regex = '/[a-zA-Z0-9\-][^_ss\d][^_\d]+\.html/'; //this will do for 3 and 4 files
```

but i need to exlude images folder..

i have tried like

```
$regex = '/[^images\/][a-zA-Z0-9\-][^_ss\d][^_\d]+\.html/'; // not working
```

Where In PHP script it will work

```
$regex = '~^(?!/images/)[a-zA-Z0-9/-]+(?!_ss\d|\d)\.html$~' //works in php script
```

can some one help me out this..

Comment: I think it will be answered before I'll have time to play a bit more with it. If it will not, I'll try to answer in my free time (5 hours to go). I don't want to give untested ideas. In the meantime, [I made a test case on PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/2fQ).

Comment: Please see this if u get time.. https://drupal.org/node/2029713#comment-8214739

Answer (score 0):

Try
`/((?!images)[0-9a-zA-Z])+/[^_]*[^\d]+\.html`

Matches:

```
/magazines/sample.html 
/test/index.html
/test/folder/newstyle.html
/test/format_ss.html
```

Does not match:

```
/test/format_ss1.html
/test/folder/newstyle_1.html
/images/two.html
/images/1.html
/test/folder/newstyle1.html
/test/folder/newstyle_12.html
```

is this acceptable?

Comment: You can verify it on an [online Regex Checker](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), do you know why it's not working or where it's failing?

Comment: @kjhhf:  i don't specfic reason for it. but    ~^(?!/images/)[a-zA-Z0-9/-]+(?!_ss\d|\d)\.html$~.. this will work very fine in php script.. but it is not working in Drupal

Answer (score 0):

It's a Drupal/Migrate specific issue - the regex is only a regex for the filename (not the directory) as eventually it gets passed to https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_scan_directory/7

> file_scan_directory($dir, $mask, $options = array(), $depth = 0)
>
> $mask: The preg_match() regular expression of the files to find.

I think the only way to exclude certain directories is to throw a false in the prepareRow() function if the row has a path you don't require.

> function prepareRow($row)
> The prepareRow() method is called by the source class next() method, after loading the data row. The argument $row is a stdClass object containing the raw data as provided by the source. There are two primary reasons to implement prepareRow():
>
> To modify the data row before it passes through any further methods and handlers: for example, fetching related data, splitting out source fields, combining or creating new source fields based on some logic.
>
> **To conditionally skip a row (by returning FALSE).**

https://www.drupal.org/node/1132582

Comment: Could you add some content from the link?

Comment: content added and more complete answer